# Permissions error when opening file in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have access file and when i try to open i got this error:

> You do not have the necessary permissions for this object XX...
>   Ask the administrator or user who created this object to
>   create the appropriate permissions for you

is there any way to open it ? or any tool for this ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, that error means that the database is secured with Jet user-level security, and is using a custom workgroup with a different ADMIN account than the default. It could be simply an indication that you have the wrong workgroup file.